# Can fish live in the dark completely?

Tags: zoology

I have got 6 pet fishes in an algae ridden  tank.  My plan is to place the tank completely away from sunlight so the algae dies.  How would this affect my fish? 
Edit: Just checked all my fishes died today.  Either its the lack of light or just that i forgot to add the chlorine removal or water pump.

Comment: @Remi.b why would it be?  I just want to kill the algea not the fish

Comment: @Remi.b I don't disagree that this sounds ill-advised, but I am also curious what would make it actually illegal.

Comment: Probably depends on the kind of fish: there are some fish that live in the ocean depths, or in caves.  You might also ask whether the darkness would actually kill the algae, or just make it go dormant until the tank is placed in the light again.

Comment: Why not just get some snails to eat the algae?

Comment: Or clean the tank once in a while?

Comment: What kind of fish were they? Was there algal bloom?

Comment: Excessive algal bloom is normally because of sunlight and lots of iron/phosphate/chalk/ micronutrients in the water: tapwater that causes limescale... I lived in a house where the water caused massive algal blooms out of control. if you switch to rainwater on the contrary it keeps the water transparent for a long time. Try goldfish first. they are very tough. I had dead fish when i was young and later i kept puffer fish and exotic fish very easily by not keeping the aquarium like a child.

Comment: all you have to do to keep the water good in difficult times, is change half of the water and clean the water pump. dont use tap water unless it is very soft water (no limescale). the solution is to use good water, not to put your fish in the dark until the algea dies. and don't use anti-chlorine, use natural water which didn't have industrial treatments.

Answer (score 1):

As noted fish live in the dark , to the extent that they no longer have eyes.As noted the algae will just go dormant until there is light. I use plants to compete with the algae for nutrients , works well. Algaecide is not a long term solution. I expect you could find some lights which have very little output in the frequencies/ spectrum needed by chlorophyll ( and block any sunlight) but you still have light to see the fish.

Answer (score 0):

Fish can live in the dark completely however they will potentially have no source of food at most Algae cannot reproduce without sunlight.

Some new research has been conducted where algae can gain energy from other means apart from the sunlight including dim light from hydrothermal vents deep in the ocean. https://indianapublicmedia.org/amomentofscience/photosynthesis-without-sunlight/

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of fish that live in environments without any light (below 1000m in the ocean there is no useful light for vision), however most aquarium fish have not evolved to live in those sorts of conditions. In the future, I think your best bet would be to remove the fish, clean the tank, and then try to manage your nutrient inputs so that the algae doesn't grow out of control.